# Need to understand how are the bit values chosen below in the application

Tags: bit

Can someone explain me how the bit values are decided in the below code -

```
   {code}
   //Each bit represents an application for paging.

   typedef uint32_t PageOrig;
   static const PageOrig    pageNotInitiated_c  = 0x0000;
   static const PageOrig    smSig_c = 0x0001;
   static const PageOrig    smData_c = 0x0002;
   static const PageOrig    nwkInitDetach_c = 0x0004;
   static const PageOrig    cancelLoc_c = 0x0008;
   static const PageOrig    lcsSig_c = 0x0010;
   static const PageOrig    gmmInfo_c = 0x0020;
   static const PageOrig    msInfo_c = 0x0040;
   static const PageOrig    oneXRtt_c = 0x0080;
   static const PageOrig    sgsapCs_c = 0x0100;
   static const PageOrig    sgsapPs_c = 0x0200;
   static const PageOrig    subsOffload_c = 0x0400;
   static const PageOrig    ehrpd_c = 0x0800;
   static const PageOrig    smSgsCs_c = 0x1000;
   static const PageOrig    smSgsPs_c = 0x2000;
   static const PageOrig    onDemandPaging_c = 0x4000;
   static const PageOrig    slnPaging_c = 0x8000;
   static const PageOrig    smNpli_c = 0x10000;
   static const PageOrig    smsSgd_c = 0x20000;
   {code}
```

This is used as an indicator to take different actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, each constant has the type "unsigned integer with 32 bits" (or 4 bytes). Each constant represents something lika a state, or a "switch" that indicates if a property is set or not. The switch is on, whe the bit is 1.

For example:

```
pageNotInitiated_c  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 

smData_c            00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010
msInfo_c            00000000 00000000 00000000 01000000
smNpli_c            00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000
```

If you want to assign ("switch on") the states `smData_c`, `smInfo_c` and `smNpli_c` to `pageState` you do this:

```
uint32_t pageState = smData_c | msInfo_c | smNpli_c ;
```

`|` means bitwise `Or`.
The result is `00000000 00000001 00000000 01000010` .

If you want to test if `pageState` has a specific switch or property set `on`, you do this:

```
if (pageState && smData_c && smInfo_c && smNpli_c)
  { ... }
```

`&&` means logical `And`. This `if` statement tests if `pageState` contains the bits `smData_c` and `smInfo_c` and `smNpli_c`. `pageState` may also contain other bits/switches that are "on" in this moment.